# Change array keys of nested array on multidimensional array from integer to alphabet

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
array (
  'A' => 
  array (
    'topic' => 'My topic name',
    'starttime' => '12/11/2018 16:30:00',
    'endtime' => '12/11/2018 18:00:00',
    'webinarid' => '1235',
    'webinarkey' => '123518238123',
    'orgkey' => '',
    'regurl' => 'https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/xxx',
    'description' => 'Long desc',
    'newsletteremailid' => '321',
    'ogimage' => 'https://xxx',
    'presenterurl' => 'https://xxx',
    'elite' => '1',
    'postid' => '699599',
  ),
  'B' => 
  array (
    'topic' => 'Topic title',
    'starttime' => '12/4/2018 16:30:00',
    'endtime' => '12/4/2018 18:00:00',
    'webinarid' => '123512',
    'webinarkey' => '8127317327132',
    'orgkey' => '',
    'regurl' => 'https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/xxx',
    'description' => 'Topic description',
    'newsletteremailid' => '316',
    'ogimage' => 'https://xxx',
    'presenterurl' => '',
    'elite' => '1',
    'postid' => '8235123'
    )
)
```

I trying to get each nested array from 0..x to be converted to alphabet.  So for example 'topic' is 'A', and 'orgkey' is 'F'.

Then return a new multidimensional array ('A' => array('A' => 'My topic name', 'B' => '12/11/2018 16:30:00')) and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of the alphabet and loop through the array, replacing the key with the letter of the alphabet at the same index.

https://paiza.io/projects/_ICIlEET4tieXtsN4MF4rw

```
$alph = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

$arr=array('A'=>array('topic'=>'My topic name','starttime'=>'12/11/2018 16:30:00','endtime'=>'12/11/2018 18:00:00','webinarid'=>'1235','webinarkey'=>'123518238123','orgkey'=>'','regurl'=>'https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/xxx','description'=>'Long desc','newsletteremailid'=>'321','ogimage'=>'https://xxx','presenterurl'=>'https://xxx','elite'=>'1','postid'=>'699599'),'B'=>array('topic'=>'Topic title','starttime'=>'12/4/2018 16:30:00','endtime'=>'12/4/2018 18:00:00','webinarid'=>'123512','webinarkey'=>'8127317327132','orgkey'=>'','regurl'=>'https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/xxx','description'=>'Topic description','newsletteremailid'=>'316','ogimage'=>'https://xxx','presenterurl'=>'','elite'=>'1','postid'=>'8235123'));

$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key1 => $val1){
    $i=0;
    foreach($val1 as $key2 => $val2){
        $newKey = "";
        //this if/else statement sets the key from A-Z, then AA, AB, etc.
        if($i > count($alph) - 1){
            $newKey = $alph[floor($i / count($alph)-1)].$alph[$i % count($alph)];
        }else{
            $newKey = $alph[$i];
        }
        $newArr[$key1][$newKey] = $val2;
        $i++;
    }
}

print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: This is a very complicated approach to something that can be done with built in functions in php.

Comment: @RyanH my code accounts for the instance when the number of array elements exceeds the number of letters in the alphabet.

Comment: @RyanH _very complicated_ ? I'd argue it's, of the solutions presented, probably the easiest to understand. Granted, it's a bit more verbose, but for a beginner-intermediate PHP developer this solution is great because, unlike the built-in functions, it shows exactly how the outcome is constructed. +1 for symlink.

Comment: Actually in the end, I used your answer because it was the easiest to modify for my needs.  I mistakenly downvoted you in the beginning due to complexity.  That was my mistake.  Please make an edit so I can upvote and mark you as my answer, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any integer/numeric keys; but assuming they are already in the proper order, just create a range of letters and combine those keys with the existing values.  This will only work up to `Z`. To then wrap to `AA` etc.. would be much more involved and probably need to ask another question:

```
foreach($array as &$values) {
    $values = array_combine(range(chr(65), chr(64+count($array))), $values);
}
```

If they are not in order then you have to assign each one:

```
foreach($array as $key => $values) {
    $result[$key] = ['A' => $values['topic'], 'B' => $values['starttime']]; // etc...
}
```

I can't really think of any reason to do this so you may want to rethink your approach.

Comment: Thx.  On the range(), how can the end range be made dynamic to the length of the array?

Comment: Edited in using ascii values.  This will only work up to Z.  To then wrap to AA etc.. would be much more involved and probably need to ask another question.

Comment: This could cause unexpected behavior if you get more than 26, cause after 'Z' you get into brackets in the ascii table.

Comment: @RyanH Yes, _This will only work up to Z_

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk($data, function(&$value){
    $keys = array_splice(range('A', 'Z', 1), 0, count($value));
    $value = array_combine($keys, $value);
});
```

this will work for any length data array ... well up to 26 items that is

Comment: If you'd like to see the full running code https://3v4l.org/JA9VS

Comment: Good one!  However you don't need the `$value = array_values($value);`

Comment: very good point @AbraCadaver, updated the answer, thanks!